# How to assign a variable of type (x:number)=>{y:number,z:number}?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a variable `foo` to be initialized. My attempt below does not compile.

```
let foo: (x: number)=>{y:number,z: number}= (x)=>{x+1,x+2};
```

with the following error:

> Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.ts(2695)
> (parameter) x: number

## Question

What is the correct way to initialize the variable `foo`?

Comment: `{x+1,x+2}` isn’t even a proper object literal. It should be `({ y: x + 1, z: x + 2 })`. See [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](/q/28770415/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of how arrow function notation works, the curly braces around the output are interpreted as containing the function body instead of a value being returned.

There are two ways around this. One is to use the longer arrow function notation, with a `return` statement. The other is to wrap your object in brackets.

It also looks like you've forgot to add the `y` and `z` labels in your output.

Try one of these:

```
let foo: (x: number) => {y: number, z: number} = (x) => ({y: x+1, z: x+2});
```

```
let foo: (x: number) => {y: number, z: number} = (x) => {
    return {y: x+1, z: x+2};
};
```

It's also worth noting that when initialising a variable in this way, TypeScript is able to infer its type. So you can actually shorten your code to just one of these:

```
let foo = (x: number) => ({y: x+1, z: x+2});
```

```
let foo = (x: number) => {
    return {y: x+1, z: x+2};
};
```

Comment: Or even: `let foo = (x: number) => ({y: x+1, z: x+2});`

Comment: Good point, thanks @AlekseyL. I'll edit my answer to include that syntax as another option.